# Registros duplicados en mysql

Tags: php, mysql

el registro desde un formulario html a mi base datos es todo un éxito pero ahora me encuentro con el problema que he dejado pendiente ya que no logro solucionar de mandar algún mensaje de que el registro ya existe, ya intente algunas cosas pero no me resultan...

Codigo de .php que realizar la inserción a la tabla

```
<?php session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['Usuario'])){?>

<html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<head>   
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo4.css" type="text/css" media="all">
 <title>Confirmación</title>  
</head>

<body>
 <div id=header>
  <img src="images/logocfe.png" width="200" height="100" alt="Logo CFE" />
  <table width="1339" class="barra" height="30" border="0" bgcolor="#336633">
         <td></td>
  </table>
 </div>
 <div>
  <?php     
   $direccion_ip=$_POST['direccion_ip']; 
   $mascara_de_subred=$_POST['mascara_de_subred'];
   $ocupada_por=$_POST['ocupada_por'];
   $nodo=$_POST['nodo'];
   $switch_panel=$_POST['switch_panel'];
   $idDpto=$_POST['idDpto'];
  ?>

  <div class="menu" id=registro>
    <center><h1>Datos de Registro dados de Alta</h1>

       Dirección IP: <?php echo $direccion_ip; ?><br>
       Máscara de Subred: <?php echo $mascara_de_subred; ?><br>
       Ocupada por: <?php echo $ocupada_por; ?><br>
       Nodo: <?php echo $nodo; ?><br>
       Switch/Panel: <?php echo $switch_panel; ?><br>
       Departamento: <?php echo $idDpto; ?><br>
    </center>
    </div>
    <?php

      $direccion_ip=$_POST['direccion_ip'];
      $mascara_de_subred=$_POST['mascara_de_subred'];
      $ocupada_por=$_POST['ocupada_por'];
      $nodo=$_POST['nodo'];
      $switch_panel=$_POST['switch_panel'];
      $idDpto=$_POST['idDpto'];

      include('libreria2.php');

      $insert = "INSERT INTO ips (direccion_ip, mascara_de_subred, ocupada_por, nodo, switch_panel, idDpto) VALUES ('$direccion_ip', '$mascara_de_subred', '$ocupada_por', '$nodo', '$switch_panel', '$idDpto')";
      conectar_bd($insert) ;


      echo "<center><br>Dirección IP dada de alta corectamente<br></center>";



    ?>
    </div>
    <center><a id="submit" href='altaip.php'>Registrar otra Dirección IP</a><br></center>
    <center><a id="submit" href='menu.php'>Volver al menú</a><br></center>
</body>  
</html> 
<?php
  }else{
   echo 'echo <script> window.location="index.php"; </script>';
  }
?>
```

Tanto "direccion_ip" como "nodo" las declare como Unique por lo que como tal en efecto el registro duplicado no se refleja en la BD pero si me da el mensaje de éxito en la pagina

Código .php de conexión a la BD

```
   <?php

 function conectar_bd($query)
 {
 $DB_SERVER = "xxx.xxx.com";
 $DB_USER = "user";
 $DB_DATABASE = "xxx";
 $DB_PWD = "123";

 $conn=mysqli_connect($DB_SERVER, $DB_USER,$DB_PWD, $DB_DATABASE);
 /* check connection */
 if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n" , mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
 }
 if ($result=mysqli_query($conn,$query))
   echo mysqli_connect_error();
 return $result;
 }

?>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías compartirnos el código de `conectar_bd()`? Esa función es la que seguramente te devuelve un resultado de la operación, no? Tal vez no tiene capturado los errores.

Comment: Listo, edite la pregunta anexando el código de la conexión a la BD

Comment: declaraste los valores que no se pueden repetir en tu base de datos como unique?

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas devolver el resultado de tu query en la function "conectar_bd".  Si el INSERT fue un exito, despliegas el mensaje de exito, sino, despliegas otro mensaje diciendo cual fue el error.

```
function conectar_bd($query)
 {
     $DB_SERVER = "serverdb.cfe.mx";
     $DB_USER = "jair";
     $DB_DATABASE = "dbIPs";
     $DB_PWD = "123";

     $conn=mysqli_connect($DB_SERVER, $DB_USER,$DB_PWD, $DB_DATABASE);
     /* check connection */
     if (mysqli_connect_errno())
     {
         printf("Connect failed: %s\n" , mysqli_connect_error());
         exit();
     }
     $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
     if ($result)
         return 'Success';
     } else {
         return 'Failure'
     }
}
```

Tambien tienes que cambiar estas lineas:

```
 conectar_bd($insert) ;

 echo "<center><br>Dirección IP dada de alta corectamente<br></center>";
```

Por esto:

```
 $result = conectar_bd($insert) ;
 if ($result == 'Success') {
     echo "<center><br>Dirección IP dada de alta corectamente<br></center>";
 } else {
     echo "<center><br>Dirección IP dada ya existe<br></center>";
 }
```

Comment: Como lo podría realizar?? Edite la pregunta anexando el código de la conexión a la BD

Comment: Ya edite mi respuesta

Comment: Aplique el código que me indicas pero sigue sin darme algún resultado

Comment: Tambien tienes que cambiar tu logica.  Mira mi edicion.

Comment: Muchas gracias! 
Quedo resuelto, saludos!

Comment: para debug puedes agregar `echo("Errorcode: " . mysqli_errno($conn));` justo después de hacer el query, `0` es no hubo error, `Error: 1169 SQLSTATE: 23000 (ER_DUP_UNIQUE)`

Answer (score 0):

No es una buena idea darle a la base de datos una carga de la lógica del proyecto, eso crea complejidad adicional en el mantenimiento del código. Lo recomendable es hacer una consulta previa (SELECT) preguntando si la dirección IP existe y de no ser así, entonces hacer el INSERT.

Respondiendo tu pregunta, modifica esta parte:

```
conectar_bd($insert) ;
echo "<center><br>Dirección IP dada de alta corectamente<br></center>";
```

Por:

```
if(conectar_bd($insert)) {
    echo "<center><br>Dirección IP dada de alta corectamente<br></center>";
} else {
    echo "<center><br>La direccion IP no ha podido ser insertada<br></center>";
}
```

Comment: y por que no aprovechar y desde el inicio decirle que sea unique determinados campos en las tablas? eso no es carga extra a la bd ese es parte de su trabajo

Comment: La base de datos va a hacer su trabajo, es cierto y va a aceptar o no el registro dependiendo de su condición de UNIQUE. Pero devuelve a PHP un error y no es la forma más elegante de comunicárselo a la aplicación. Los campos UNIQUE, INDEX, etc... son para darle integridad y coherencia a los datos de la base.

Comment: Gracias por su apoyo, pero acabo de probar modificando esa parte del código pero aún así sigue mostrándome que los datos fueron dados de alta con éxito... aclaro que efectivamente tanto ''dirección_ip" como ''nodo'' están declarados como Unique

Comment: Olvidé la línea siguiente en "modifica esta parte". Ya lo edité en la respuesta. Obviamente siempre va a salir el mensaje porque siempre lo está ejecutando.

Comment: Claro, ya lo tome en cuenta y lo modifique de esa forma pero aún así sigue este detalle

Answer (score 0):

Lo que podrias hacer en mi opinion antes del insert es comprobar que previamente no exista en la base de datos el registro que vas a insertar ejemplo:

```
//datos del post
$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$fecha = date("Y-m-d"); 

//COMPROBACION
// Comprobamos si el usuario esta registrado

$nuevo_usuario=mysql_query("select nombre from $tabla where nombre='$nombre'");
if(mysql_num_rows($nuevo_usuario)>0)
{
echo "
<p class='avisos'>El nombre de usuario ya esta registrado</p>
<p class='avisos'><a href='javascript:history.go(-1)' class='clase1'>Volver atrás</a></p>
";
}
// ------------ Si no esta registrado el usuario continua el script
else
{
// ==============================================
// Comprobamos si el email esta registrado

$nuevo_email=mysql_query("select email from $tabla where email='$email'");
if(mysql_num_rows($nuevo_email)>0)
{
echo "
<p class='avisos'>La direccion de e-mail ya esta registrada</p>
<p class='avisos'><a href='javascript:history.go(-1)' class='clase1'>Volver atrás</a></p>
";
}
// ------------ Si no esta registrado el e-mail continua el script
else
{
$result = mysql_db_query("$base_datos","insert into $tabla (nombre,email,fecha) values ('$nombre','$email','$fecha')"); 

include('cierra_db.php');

// Confirmamos que el registro ha sido insertado con exito

echo "
<p class='avisos'>Registro insertado con exito</p>
<p class='avisos'><a href='javascript:history.go(-1)' class='clase1'>Volver atrás</a></p>
";
} 
// ==============================================
}
```

Es un pequeño ejemplo claro, existen muchas formas de hacerlo y optimizar el codigo
siempre antes de un insert deberias tener un metodo o funcion que vaya a consultar en tu db si existe la data que vas a insertar en caso de existir  pues retornas un mensje de el registro existente lo podrias mostrar al usuario un mensaje

```
"Registro existen desea modificarlo ?"
```

si no existe el registro insertarlo y notificar al usuario del insert correcto !
suerte !!